# Determining the effective file permissions

Tags: permissions

I would like to ask what are the rules that Linux OS's are using on `ext4` file systems when there are conflicts between directory permission and file permissions.

Example:

```
 drwxrwx--- user1 group2 FOLDER
 -rw-r--r-- user1 group1 FILE
```

What permissions a user in a `group2` on a file `FILE` would have?...And what is the general rule for determining file permissions in this situations?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If a user is in group2, then they'd follow the group permissions for the directory FOLDER. i.e.

```
rwx
```

Presuming that they are not user1 and also not in group1, then we'd look at the "other" permissions for FILE. i.e.

```
r--
```

Hence, they only have read permissions for this file. Note that this is a bit confusing. They cannot directly modify this file, since don't have write privileges. However, since they have `wx` for the directory, they could `rm` this file, then replace it with a new one. (N.B. the inode would probably change, and they wouldn't be able to `chown` it to the original owner, so it's not exactly the same as directly modifying the file.)

So in general, the permissions inherit from the most-parent directory. As permissions get more restrictive, they restrict the children files and directories. However, as above, if you have `wx` permissions to the top-level directory, there are workarounds.

---

#### EDIT

Similarly, if you edit the file with `vim`, then you'll see a change in inode. It's not "editing" it, but "over-writing" it.

```
$ echo foo > file
$ ls -li file 
5213942 -rw-r--r-- 1 sparhawk sparhawk 4 Aug 16 15:34 file
$ sudo chown root:root file
$ ls -li file 
5213942 -rw-r--r-- 1 root root 4 Aug 16 15:34 file
$ vim file
$ ls -li file 
5214750 -rw-r--r-- 1 lee lee 7 Aug 16 15:35 file
```

Note the change in inode after `vim` overwrites the file. Also note that vim gave a warning that the file was readonly. I had to save with `:w!`.

Comment: Actually , that was my real question. Is there any general rule, like following the rule of the lowest permission or something like that, like in Windows?

Comment: In fact, I tried to change the content of the mentioned file in Fedora 18 in this set up and it did let me do it. But when the next time I run the command ls -l it showed this output

Comment: Sort of. However, you really have to traverse the entire directory to tell. For example, if you have two directories, a `-wx` parent and `+wx` child, you cannot write in the parent, but can in the child. Start at the top-most directory, and read down. If you encounter a `-x`, then you can't progress any more. If you encounter a `-w`, then you *might* be able to.

Comment: -rw-r--r-- user group2 FILE

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Did the user change from `user` to `user1`, and group change too? What is your username? Also, how did you "change the content"?

Comment: User1 was owner of the file and after I execute the command that changed the file, the owner became the user that executed the command

Comment: What was the command?

Comment: vi [the name of the target file]

Comment: I think this behaviour is consistent. I've edited the answer so I can format nicely. (I don't have `vi`, but `vim` probably works the same.)

Comment: Well, I was told that I didnt modified the file , but that I ovewwritten it, which is the most probable explenation. Thank you anyway for your efforts, I found your answers very helpful

Comment: @majestik33 I'm not sure what you mean. I edited my answer to say exactly that: i.e. you overwrote the file, but didn't "modify" it?